# SQlite WHERE statement not working?

Tags: java, android, sql

I am making an app that stores books titles, a date added and a date that the book needs to be returned by. Below, I show the `where` statement that gets all books that are due to be returned between today's date and two days hence, returned as a listview. It does not work, however, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong:

```
    public Cursor fetchAllDue() {

    //get todays date
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentDay=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //Add days on to todays date
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay+2);
    cal.getTime(); //Result

    //format back to string
    String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").format(cal.getTime());


  //get todays date
    Calendar cal1=Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentDay1=cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //Atodays date
    cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay1);
    cal1.getTime(); //Result

    //format back to string
    String formattedDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").format(cal1.getTime());


    //body = date added, needs to be changed
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY, KEY_EXTRA, KEY_DUE }, KEY_DUE + " BETWEEN 'formattedDate1' and 'formattedDate2'", null, null, null, null);
}
```

This is the code for when the date is input for the "due date":

```
                //convert string to int.
            int myNum = Integer.parseInt(editbox3.getText().toString());

            //get todays date
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            int currentDay=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            //Add days on to todays date
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay+myNum);
            cal.getTime(); //Result

            //formate back to string
            String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").format(cal.getTime());


            bundle.putString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DUE,formattedDate
                    .toString());
```

The dates are all strings. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does 'not working' mean an error or unexpected results?

Comment: Well it does not display any books in the listview. So unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty certain this will work buddy.

Essentially a mix of the two other answers.

```
     String[] params = new String[] { String.valueOf(formattedDate1), String.valueOf(formattedDate2) };

     return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE duedate BETWEEN ? AND ?", params);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks you! Worked first time. You are a G!

Comment: I would like to know, and it's a common thing here in stackOverflow, to comment the downvote. Please.

Answer (score 2):

You query is wrong. You use `formattedDate1` and `formattedDate2` but your code is setting `formattedDate` and `formattedDate1`, not to mention quite important fact that these does not make into your query as you do not pass it. It should be something like:

```
String where = KEY_DUE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?";
String[] args = { String.valueOf(formattedDate1), String.valueOf(formattedDate2) };
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, where, args, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by this. Could you explain what the "" BETWEEN ? AND ?";" because it needs to say 

BETWEEN todays date and 2 days from nows date. 


I also dont understand this bit 

`String[] args = { String.valueOf(formattedDate1), String.valueOf(formattedDate2) };`

Comment: @Ruddy - you aren't passing the query parameters properly.  The parameters should use '?' as placeholders, and an array containing the values of these parameters (or variables holding these values) should follow the query string.  Your original query had the parameters hard-coded as 'formattedDate1' and 'formattedDate2' which is not the correct syntax...

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer of **WebnetMobile** is the right one!

With SQLite on Android I always use a `INTEGER` field containing the UNIX time stamp of the date. So I can get queries to be executed more quickly and with no `WHERE` or string-date conversion problems.

```
Date date;
...
long timeStamp = date.getTime();
```

You can also try to use dates as parameters for the query:

```
Date from, to;
long timeStampFrom = from.getTime();
long timeStampTo = to.getTime();

String[] params = new String[] { String.valueOf(from), String.valueOf(to) };
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + getTableName() + " WHERE DateTime BETWEEN ? AND ?", params);
```

or if you want to use UNIX timestamp:

```
String[] params = new String[] { String.valueOf(timeStampFrom ), String.valueOf(timeStampTo )) };
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + getTableName() + " WHERE DateTime BETWEEN ? AND ?", params);
```

Comment: Again, What is the "BETWEEN ? AND ?". There should be todays date and 2 days from now. Thank you both for your replys, if you could help some more would be great.

Comment: The ? character is a placeholder for the parameter you pass to rawQuery() function. So params[] contains the 'from' and 'to' date. When executing the query, the dbmanager replace the '? character whit the values of params[]. The first '?' is replaced by the first element in params[], the second '? by the second in params[]. Is it clear for you?